# Does the Ultrasonic Fence raise alien aggression?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

The [Ultrasonic Fence](http://civilizationbeyondearth.gamepedia.com/Ultrasonic_Fence) repels aliens in Beyond Earth, but its not clear what effect it has on alien aggression.  In the current game I'm playing I have an [alien nest](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_nest_%28CivBE%29) within my borders in an attempt to improve relations with the aliens, but I'm not sure what effect the fence will have on alien aggression

Will the Ultrasonic Fence raise alien aggression?

What effect, if any, can it have on alien nests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The summary states:

> The Ultrasonic Fence is a defensive structure which prevents alien lifeforms from invading the space around your cities, creating a passive, **non-aggressive** barrier between yourself and the neutral alien lifeforms.

A non-aggressive barrier in my understanding will not alter the alien aggression in any way, so your free to use it and not get a load of angry aliens knocking on your door.